# How can I get current hover id which class name unavailable usign jquery and pass this id use ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

anybody help me to find current "id" in hover effect where "unavailable" class exist. Example id(1_1);
Also pass this id via ajax request.

```
    <div class="seatCharts-row">
     <div class="seatCharts-cell seatCharts-space"></div>
     <div id="1_1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available">1</div>
     <div id="1_2" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available">2</div>
     <div class="seatCharts-cell seatCharts-space"></div>
     <div id="1_4" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell unavailable">3</div>
     <div id="1_5" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell unavailable">4</div>
    </div>
```

Advanced thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please try this**

```
$(".unavailable").hover(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id'))
});
```

The hover() method specifies two functions to run when the mouse pointer hovers over the selected elements.
This method triggers both the mouseenter and mouseleave events.
**Note:** If only one function is specified, it will be run for both the mouseenter and mouseleave events.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.unavailable').mouseover(function() {
   alert(this.id);
});
```